# In jsonschema, how do I validate objects where the keys can be anything, and the values must be of a specific type?

Tags: jsonschema

I'm trying to use jsonschema to validate objects consisting of sets of key-value pairs. The keys can be named anything, but all the values must share a specific type.

The type is a complex object, but I think we can pretend it's just an int.

How can I write jsonschema to validate these objects?

```
{
  "foo" : 1,
  "bar" : 2,
  "baz" : 3
}
```

-> Passes

```
{
  "aaa" : 10,
  "bbb" : 20,
  "ccc" : 30
}
```

-> Passes

```
{
  "z" : 1,
  "y" : 2,
  "x" : "Not an int!"
}
```

-> Fails

Answer (score 2):

You can use additionalProperties to specify a type. You can use http://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/ to test this quickly.

```
{
   "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
   "additionalProperties" : 
   {
        "type": "integer"
   }
}
```